# Add a select option only for Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a basic SELECT element like this:

```
<select name="bla" id="bla">
<option value="1">Opt1</option>
<option value="2">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

I want that if this component is rendered by Safari browser, it renders

```
<select name="bla" id="bla">
<option value="">Select an option</option><!-- ONLY FOR SAFARI BROWSER -->
<option value="1">Opt1</option>
<option value="2">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

What is the  faster way to implement it ?

Thanks to support

Comment: Hi B001, I mean in terms of development... If I can set a properly in css, it should be great

Comment: I think that what you want through CSS is not possible. Even if you hide the option and only show it on the safari, the first option will be the selected one, it will not appear in the drop, but it will be the default option in other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no HTML component which can condition the browser, but you can add dynamically an option with Javascript on browser detection.

```
var is_safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: warning - This could be cached right (through cloudflare etc)? so Chrome users might the shown as safari users?